# Exercise: print exercise text several times (use \shipoutExercise repeatedly)

Tags: exam, exercises

I am typesetting exams for secondary school students. The idea is to use `exercise.sty` to be able to print the answers on the back of the "exam sheet" during a tutorial.

I also want to save paper: as each "exam" contains only 2-3 problems, they fit in a half of A4 - so, the idea is to have two "exam sheets" per A4 and then cut the paper in the middle.

My hope was that the `\shipoutExercise` command of `exercise.sty` would allow  printing the problems twice. However it does not. The code below typesets the problems (and the answers) only once.

Is it possible to find a workaround for this issue?

Minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
 This is problem's text: how many?
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
 5 pieces
\end{Answer}

\shipoutExercise % print problems the 1st time

\shipoutExercise % print them the second time

%-------------
\newpage
\shipoutAnswer % print answers the first time

\shipoutAnswer % print them the second time


\end{document}
```

This is a simplified version. In the real life, the `\shipout...` commands will be wrapped in `minipage` to fill exactly 50% of an A4 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quick and dirty solution: by redefining the `\shipout...` commands in my document and making sure the corresponding boxes not get emptied after being typeset.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\shipoutExercise}{%
\global\setbox\temp@Exercisebox\copy\all@Exercisebox%
\if@ExerciseOutput\unvbox\all@Exercisebox\fi%
\global\setbox\all@Exercisebox\copy\temp@Exercisebox%
}
\renewcommand{\shipoutAnswer}{%
\global\setbox\temp@Answerbox\copy\all@Answerbox%
\if@AnswerOutput\unvbox\all@Answerbox\fi%
\global\setbox\all@Answerbox\copy\temp@Answerbox%
}
\makeatother
```

Hopefully, there is a better (more elegant - e.g., with package options?) solution.